# Scaling from the center UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, scaling

So I've been looking for this solution and don't see anything exactly what I'm looking for. This question seems like the right idea, but the answer doesn't work: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716971). I feel like there is a super easy answer I can't find.

Anyways, I have a UIImageView and when I try to use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^
         {
             uv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1,1.1);
         }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              animations:^
                              {
                                  uv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
                              }];
         }
];
```

the image scales from the upper-lefthand corner (i.e. stretches down and to the right). I want it to stretch in all directions rather than just the two. I think this has something to do with the `bounds`, `center`, or some other `UIImageView` trait.

Answer (score 0):

Set the view.center before and in the animation.

Comment: Set the `view.center` to what exactly? To `CGPointMake(uv.bounds.size.width/2, uv.bounds.size.height/2)`, `CGPointMake(uv.frame.size.width/2, uv.frame.size.height/2)`, something else?

Comment: To there where it should be before and after the animation. This could be super.view.center, you know better

Comment: When I do this, it merely moves the location of the view, it has no effect on the scaling.